# Найти длину каждого элемента из коллекции, используя map, zip, или filter

Tags: python, map, filter, zip

a = [12, 139, 99, 9787, 753, 4, 32]
Задание такое, что надо найти длину каждого элемента из этого списка, используя map, zip, или filter. Только так. Как это сделать?

Comment: `len_numbers = list(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), a))` не совсем понял что надо. Так?

Comment: Да! Всё работает. Нужно количество символов у каждого элемента списка

Answer (score 3):

```
len_numbers = list(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), a))
```

или можно еще так, для наглядности у какого элемента какая длинна .

```
a = [12, 139, 99, 9787, 753, 4, 32] 
print(list(zip(a,map(lambda x: len(str(x)), a))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну просто же всё. Можно же не один раз `map` применять, как и всё остальное:

```
a = [12, 139, 99, 9787, 753, 4, 32]
print(list(zip(a, map(len, map(str, a)))))
```

Вывод:

```
[(12, 2), (139, 3), (99, 2), (9787, 4), (753, 3), (4, 1), (32, 2)]
```

Comment: так даже красивее, чем с лямбда-функцией

Comment: Даёшь больше map'ов... `print(*map(" -> ".join, zip(map(str, a), map(str, map(len, map(str, a))))), sep="\n")` :)

Answer (score 0):

может так?

`print(list(map(len, a)))`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]